# How in one controller return HTML or JSON(PHP)

Tags: php, json, rest, yii

I have a Yii site with 2 pages `site.com/user/create` and `site.com/user/create.json`

I need to have one controller for both pages.

1. How do I make a route for these - I tried `<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>.json'=>'<controller>/<action>`) but it didn't help
2. How do I identify in controller whether the request is for JSON or HTML - I have tried `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']`, in the REST client it was OK, but in the browser I got a PHP notice `Undefined index: CONTENT_TYPE`

Comment: To get around `Undefined index: CONTENT_TYPE` you can do something like `$type = !empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] : 'text/html';` to get rid of the error and default to `text/html` for the browser - but to be honest the content type of the request would probably not be relevant, you would do far better to use a difference in the URLs to determine the content type of the response.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 ways of doing it:

1. `Yii::app()->request->getRequestUri();` will get you the request URI - check it for the .json extension at the end. The routing rule you have in your question should work and get the request to the right controller and action.
2. You can make a routing rule like this:

   ```
   <controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>.json'=>'<controller>/<action>/format/json
   ```

   and then check for the `format` parameter inside your action.

I suggest the second way since it's extendable.